# Java inheritance with methods

Tags: java

I have a question about the following MC problem:

> Given the following declarations.
>
> ```
> public class Vechicle {
>  public void test(Car x, SportsCar y) {}
> }
>
> public class Car extends Vechicle {
> }
> public class SportsCar extends Car {
> }
> ```
>
> Also consider the following code that appears in a different class.

> ```
> Vechicle v = new Vechicle();
> Car c = new Car();
> SportsCar sporty = new SportsCar();
> ```
>
> Which of the following is a correct call to test? (A)
> v.test(sporty,v); (B) sporty.test(c,c); (C) v.test(sporty,c); (D)
> sporty.test(sporty,v); (E) c.test(sporty,sporty);

Why is the answer here E? Wouldn't the first input "x" have to be an instance of "Car", not its subclass "SportsCar"?

If subclass objects are interchangeable in function definitions, why would the other answers be incorrect?

Comment: Are you saying a sports car is not a car? But: is a car a sports car?

Comment: There is a typo: Vechicle  -> Vehicle. Also the relationship of the classes seems to be wrong. The parent class `Vechicle` shouldn't know about the child classes and this would be a better and more generic method declaration: `public void test(Vehicle x, Vehicle y)`

Comment: @Boris I'm not sure what you mean - does the question not make sense as is?

Comment: The question does make sense, my comment is about a typo and a poor design.

Comment: What is “MC” mentioned if first sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `Car` object is a `Vehicle`. And every `SportsCar` object is a `Car` as well as a `Vehicle`.

But… not every `Car` object is a `SportsCar`, nor is every `Vehicle` object a `SportsCar`.

Since the first parameter of the `test` method requires a `Vehicle`, using a `SportsCar` object as that argument is correct and legitimate.

---

Let’s run through the answers.

> (A) v.test(sporty,v);

Wrong. The second argument must be a `SportsCar`. Not every `Vehicle` is a `SportsCar`.

> (B) sporty.test(c,c);

Wrong. The second argument must be a `SportsCar`. Not every `Car` is a `SportsCar`.

> (C) v.test(sporty,c);

Wrong. The second argument must be a `SportsCar`. Not every `Car` is a `SportsCar`.

> (D) sporty.test(sporty,v);

Wrong. The second argument must be a `SportsCar`. Not every `Vehicle` is a `SportsCar`.

> (E) c.test(sporty,sporty);

Correct. The first argument must be a `Car`, and every `SportsCar` object is a `Car`.

---

As [commented by Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67891697/java-inheritance-with-methods/67891926#comment120000839_67891697), the semantics of the class design here is screwy. But this is supposed to be a simple exercise in the mechanics of inheritance, not realistic code.